# How to find substrings in a string with specific first letter and last letter?

Tags: python

For example,

I have the string `'abdadqdqbdabdabdawb'`

How can I find substrings, which start with `'a'` and end with `'b'`.

The output should be:

```
['ab', 'adqdqb', 'ab', 'ab', 'awb']
```

Comment: can you show your code ? or you want us to write it ?

Comment: Well, I am a novice in python, tried billions of alternatives.. So I don't know, which one to post.

Comment: @JonasVirkutis, How about choose the option which you feel is *closest* to a good / correct solution? We usually expect correct syntax, but not necessarily code which works as desired.

Comment: string = "abdadqdqbdabdabdawb"
list = []

for i in range(0, len(string)):
    oba.append(string[i:i+5])

print([w for w in list if w.startswith("a")])

Comment: @JonasVirkutis Your example output seems to only include the first matching substring for each "a".  Should the output include the _entire_ list of substrings, which would include "abdadqdqbdabdabdawb", for example?

Comment: Well, this code creates a list with specific words of length 5 and finds one's, which start with letter a. However, I do not understand what kind of regular expressions should I use to find specific substrings that I have mentioned above.

Comment: `re.findall('a.*?b', somestring)` will get all non-overlapping strings.

Comment: Well, the output should include the list of substrings that start with letter "a" and end with letter "b". For instance, [ab, adqdqb, ... .

Comment: Is there a possibility to find overlapping strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
re.findall(r'[Aa][^Bb]*[Bb]', 'abdadqdqbdabdabdawb')
>>> ['ab', 'adqdqb', 'ab', 'ab', 'awb']
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to find overlapping strings?

Comment: Nevermind, found the solution.